# Using regex + str_replace to prep tags for jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I'm using jQuery to manipulate articles stored in a database.

Each article is divided into sections. The HTML for a typical section looks like this:

```
<section id="directions" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#directions2" class="SecCon">
  <h2><span class="label label-primary"><small><span class="only-collapsed glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span><span class="only-expanded glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></small> Directions</span>      </h2>
  <div id="directions2" class="collapse in article">
    <p>Animals have the power of locomotion.</p>
  </div>
<section>
```

It works fine; combined with some jQuery scripts, it displays each heading in the form of a button that can be clicked to open or close that section, displaying text or hiding it.

The only thing bothering me is code bloat; I have hundreds of articles to get online, and adding all that code, glyphicons, etc. is turning into a pain.

So imagine if I condensed everything before the first paragraph tag to this:

```
<section>
  <h2>Directions</h2>
    <div>
```

That would be stored in my database, but the display could be modified with str_replace and a regular expression to fill in the blanks, transforming it into the block of code I posted above. And if 'Directions' was replaced by 'Ecology', then that would be styled the same except that every instance of 'directions' would be replaced by 'ecology'.

An added advantage is that I could make major changes in the code without having to alter all my database tables.

Before I dive into this project, I just wondered if someone could tell me if this a workable scheme or a dumb idea. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: [You can't parse (X)HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630).

Comment: Is the data for your articles not stored in a database? Can you show your server code, and the format in which you're receiving your data?

Comment: @thomas - Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "server code." I'm working with PHP and MySQL. I simply query my database, then display an article by echoing $Content.

Comment: What does $content look like? Is all this data stored in once db field? There's probably a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead and store the HTML without all the extra markup.

```
<section>
    <h2>Directions</h2>
    <div>Some directions</div>
</section>
<section>
    <h2>Ecology</h2>
    <div>Ecology info</div>
</section>
```

You can use javascript/jQuery to add the id's, spans and classes without any problem. Try something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/47kegtn9/1/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('section').each(function () {
        var html,
            $this = $(this),
            $h2 = $this.children('h2'),
            sectionId = $h2.text().toLowerCase();
        $this.attr({
            class : 'SecCon',
            id : sectionId,
            'data-toggle' : 'collapse',
            'data-target' : '#' + sectionId + '2'
        });
        $h2.wrapInner('<span class="label label-primary"/>');

        html = '<small>' +
            '<span class="only-collapsed glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>' +
            '<span class="only-expanded glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>' +
            '</small>';
        $h2.find('.label').prepend(html);

        $this.children('div').attr({
            class : 'collapse in article',
            id : sectionId + '2'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, that works great! I made one mistake, though. If a header title is "Evolution," then your script creates the id "evolution." But I never thought about headers with more than one word. For example, the header "How Evolution Works" would yield the id "how evolution works". I have a fix in mind, but I may not be able to ask a new question until later today. When I do post it, I'll post a link to the new question here, for other folks who may have the same question.

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be to just replace the spaces with a dash:  `sectionId = $h2.text().toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '-');`